# How to upload a file from my sdcard with file path "sdcard/file1.pdf" to php server using volley without activity

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am a beginner in android development. I don't know how to upload a file from a particular path like "mnt/sdcard/file.xxx" to my php server using volley. How ever i am able to upload the text data to my php server using volley. here is my code which I am using where I call pploadFile("sdcard/file.xxx") from my service class.

```
public class UploadFiles extends Application{
RequestQueue queue;
JsonObjectRequest request;
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
public void pploadFile(String path){
    Log.e("Upload Class","Inside Upload Class");
    try {
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Log.e("Upload Class","Inside Upload Class1");
        // the parameters for the php
        // map.put(KEY, VALUE);
        map.put("email", "example");
        // map.put("file", "");
        // the JSON request
        // JsonObjectRequest(METHOD, URL, JSONOBJECT(PARAMETERS), OK_LISTENER, ERROR_LISTENER);
        request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, // the request method
                "http://192.168.0.118/recieve.php", // the URL
                new JSONObject(map), // the parameters for the php
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { // the response listener
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // here you parse the json response
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() { // the error listener
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                  /* here you can warn the user that there
                  was an error while trying to get the json
                  information from the php  */
                    }
                });

        // executing the quere to get the json information
        queue.add(request);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Volley Err",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us some data so that we can help you.

Comment: Slightly reworded your question to make it more in line with the policies of this site. But I agree with the comments. Beyond that: your question is probably too broad. Consider writing some code, and when you are stuck there (like running into errors), feel free to add a [mcve] to the question, so tht people can help with that.

Comment: Actually I wanted to upload some file(like jpg, pdf etc.) from my android phone memory to my Web Server using volley Library. But I have no idea how to do that using volley. I can able to HTTP POST form data like text etc but not able to HTTP POST HTTP FILES using volley library to my web server.